# why one directory is the subdirectory of another in python system path?

Tags: python, recursion, import, path, sys

my sys.path is like below:

```
/homel/ychao/python/python_lib
/usr/lib64/python27.zip
/usr/lib64/python2.7
/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gst-0.10
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions
```

I noticed there some some directories which are all subdirectories /usr/lib64/python2.7, how could it be like this? when I remove all the subdirectories and make the sys.path like this:

```
/homel/ychao/python/python_lib
/usr/lib64/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

some packages that I can import before will fail after the modification. so this means the "import" does not know to find the appropriate packages recursively?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so this means the "import" does not know to find the appropriate packages recursively?

That's right. The [docs for `sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path) don't mention recursion anywhere.

In fact, if module resolution were recursive, you'd get confusing behavior. Suppose `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ham` were on the search path, and you'd have files

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ham
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ham/ham/util.py
```

and you'd do `import util`. If no `util.py` or `util/__init__.py` were found on the search path directly, recursive processing would then cause `ham.util` to be imported with the wrong name, defeating Python's package/module namespaces.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I don't quite understand the last part. could you explaint further? "If no util.py or util/__init__.py were found on the search path directly, recursive processing would then cause ham.util to be imported with the wrong name, defeating Python's package/module namespaces."